# react-select default value set but not highlighted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-select, default-value, react-select

When I set the defaultValue in the react-select Component, it is correctly recognised and set, but is not highlighted in the select menu.

```
<Select onChange={handleChange} options={options} styles={styles} defaultValue={defaultValue} />
```

[defaultValue selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVgF5.png)

[Not highlighted in the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyq0U.png)

This is the defaultValue, and it's correct:

```
{
    "value": {
        "param_user": "TEST"
    },
    "label": "TEST"
}
```

Perhaps it is because the value is an object?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: instead of defaultValue can you please check with only "default", I had same issue and it works for me earlier.

Comment: Most probably, the select identifies the default value by comparing by reference. If the default value is not part of the options array, but rather a separate object, it cannot determine what value from the select to show as selected. Try finding the default value in the options array and supplying that as the default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the problem arrises because the default implementation of react-select checks whether the option is selected by reference. This means that if your default option does not come from the options array itself, it will not display as selected. Fortunately, the react-select library allows you to pass in a predicate that determines whether an option is selected. In your case:

```
const isOptionSelected = (option, selectValue) => selectValue.some(
  (val) => val.value.param_user === option.value.param_user
);
<Select isOptionSelected={isOptionSelected} onChange={handleChange} options={options} styles={styles} defaultValue={defaultValue} />
```